# Return Instance of a case class dynamically with pattern matching

Tags: scala

I have different case classes and objects for that case class, and I am trying to instantiate the class object and return that class.

```
case class KeySet(KeyID:String,KeyName:String,KeyType:String)
object KeySet{
  def fromXml(node: scala.xml.Node):KeySet = {
    //some operation
    new KeySet(KeyID,KeyName,KeyType)
  }
}

case class NodeSet(NodeID:String,NodeValue:String,NodeType:String,NodeKey:String,NodeLocation:String)
object NodeSet{
  def fromXml(node: scala.xml.Node):NodeSet = {
    //some operation
    new KeySet(NodeID,NodeValue,NodeType,NodeKey,NodeLocation)
  }
}
```

and I have a method to create an instance of a class and return class object.

```
def getConnectionDetails(connectionType:String) : Option[Class[_]]= {
     connectionType match {
       case "KeySet" => Some(() => {
         val xml_cred= scala.xml.XML.loadString("xmlfile")
         KeySet.fromXml(xml_cred)
       })
       case "NodeSet" => Some(() => {
         val xml_cred= scala.xml.XML.loadString("xmlfile")
         NodeSet.fromXml(xml_cred)
       })
       case _ => None
     }
   }
```

Here i am getting the error in Return type, each case will return different case class.
what would be the return type for this method?.

Comment: In your code above, in both cases you are constructing a ```KeySet``` including in the second case. That can't be right.

Comment: Are you looking for `Option[AnyRef]`? `Class[_]` is a type representing types, not one representing any class.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should have a parent ```trait``` that both these classes fall under and return that type. These kind of loose typing is dangerous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the only common ancestor between two case classes is `AnyRef`, hence the type which can be used as function result type. But, using `AnyRef` or `Any` is highly un-recommended practice, because of lost type safety.

Instead,  what you need to dot is to form `Sum Type`, via using common `sealed trait`, like shown below:

```
sealed trait ConnectionDetails

case class KeySet(keyID: String, keyName: String, keyType: String) extends ConnectionDetails

case class NodeSet(nodeID: String, nodeValue: String, nodeType: String, nodeKey: String, nodeLocation: String) extends ConnectionDetails


def getConnectionDetails(connectionType:String) : Option[ConnectionDetails]= {
     connectionType match {
       case "KeySet" =>
         val xml_cred= scala.xml.XML.loadString("xmlfile")
         Some(KeySet.fromXml(xml_cred))

       case "NodeSet" => 
         val xml_cred= scala.xml.XML.loadString("xmlfile")
         Some(NodeSet.fromXml(xml_cred))
       case _ => None
     }
   }
```

So, in all other places you can do pattern match against `ConnectionDetails` and this will be safe.

Hope this helps!